# How to programmatically change the month in Material Calendar <mat-calendar>

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm using the Material Calendar Component with custom navigation that I've built which shows the next 5 days after you select a date in the calendar.

When you select a date in the custom element it updates the Calendar with the newly selected date, but if the incoming date is in the next month, I would like the Calendar, to switch to that month automatically.

HTML:

```
<mat-calendar [selected]="selectedDate" (selectedChange)="onDateSelected($event)"
  [minDate]="minDate" [dateClass]="dateClass"></mat-calendar>
```

TS:

```
@Input() set incomingDate(d: Date) {
    this.selectedDate = d; // sets the incoming date on mat-calendar
    this.dateClass(d); // highlights the next 5 days in the mat-calendar
    this.calendar.updateTodaysDate(); // re-renders calendar to see changes
}
```

Is there any method that I can bind to the  element to solve this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `_goToDateInView` for that. It won't change the date object, it will just go to the month you pass as a parameter, therefore you can keep your date selection logic intact.

```
/** Handles year/month selection in the multi-year/year views. */
_goToDateInView(date: D, view: 'month' | 'year' | 'multi-year'): void;
```

And here is how you could use it:

Template

```
<mat-calendar #calendar></mat-calendar>
```

Component

```
@ViewChild('calendar', {static: false}) calendar: MatCalendar<Date>;

public goToDate() {
   this.calendar._goToDateInView(someDateObjectInAnotherMonth, 'month')
}
```

[**Stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zrp5rg)

Comment: So weird this isn't public.

Comment: @Simon_Weaver Totally agree. I had to dig deep to find that method. There are plenty cases like this one. It’s really poorly documented

Comment: @Dino I am using momen() for date and your solution is not working for me. Do you any suggestions for that?

Comment: @dino Do you know how to do this with the ``<mat-date-range-picker>``? When using this component it doesn't have ``<mat-calendar>``?

Comment: Thanks Dino, this worked perfectly for me!

Answer (score 7):

##### Use `[startAt]` to jump automatically to the specified month

```
    <mat-calendar [minDate]="minDate" 
                  [maxDate]="maxDate" 
                  [startAt]="nextShipmentDt()"
                  [selected]="nextShipmentDt()"></mat-calendar>
```

Comment: This answer does not reset the viewtype. Tnx!

Comment: IMO it should be an approved answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

you can try also the following. (worked for me after I checked the implementation -> [MatCalendar](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/datepicker/calendar.ts)).

```
this.calendar.activeDate = this.selectedDate; // set the active date to the selected date
this.calendar.updateTodaysDate(); // update calendar state
```

Answer (score 1):

This workaround using Render (angular 10 is Render2) work for me

https://mariazacharia-k.medium.com/build-a-custom-calendar-with-angular-material-calendar-ebb6806308e5